# Вызов С++ функции из Python

Tags: c++, python, c

Есть Python скрипт имеющий путь к файлу, необходимо открыть этот файл в С/С++ функции, провести с ним манипуляции и вернуть результат в Python скрипт.

Прочитал: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html, но так и не понял как все это сделать.

Comment: Делал что-то такое, но очень простое: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/using_custom_dll В папке `mydll2` можно найти код функции и файл проект visual studio, через которую собирал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Здесь очень хороший пример как это сделать github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/using_custom_‌​dll

Вот пример для UNIX, на основе указанного выше

test.py

```
from ctypes import *

libc = CDLL("libmath.so")
print(libc.add(1, 2))
print(libc.sub(1, 2))
```

math.c

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int sub(int a, int b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

сборка в библиотеку (shared library)

```
gcc -shared -o libmath.so -fPIC math.c
```

Запуск как и всегда

```
python test.py
```

Comment: Маленькое уточнение: если разделяемая библиотека делается самостоятельно и именно на C++ (ну, мало ли, проще написать что-то на C++, чем на Питоне), то вызываемые функции должны быть объявлены как `extern "C"`.

Comment: Пример c использованием C++ https://bitbucket.org/shotInLeg/callcppfunctionfrompython